# What does EA Games use to develop games for iPhone?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

What does EA Games (Electronic Arts) use to develop iPhone games with such high graphic quality? Does it use the built-in OpenGL functionality, or do they have an engine which we can use like the Unity game development engine?

Comment: Most likely an in-house tool. Although I have heard of big game houses using UnrealSDK.

Answer (score 1):

All engines on iOs render using OpenGL ES. EA like most big publishers works with many platforms. It was a big endorsement in 2010 when [EA said they would use Unity3D for some of their titles](http://techcrunch.com/2010/09/22/ea-unity/). Check out the ["Made with Unity"](http://unity3d.com/gallery/made-with-unity/game-list) page for more titles using the engine.